# Mysql update table at the same time

Tags: mysql, asynchronous, synchronized

Let's say in mysql, I want to update a column in one of the table. I need to SELECT the record and change the value, after that, UPDATE it back to the database. In some case, I couldn't do these 2 operations in one sql query and nest them into subquery (due to mysql limitation), I have to load it into program (let's say Java), change the value, and then put back into database.

For example, program A get a column's value and want to increase it with one and then put it back. At the same time, program B want to do the same thing too. Before program A put back the increased value, program B already get the wrong value (program B is supposed to get the value that is increased by program A, but it run at the same time as program A, so it retrieved the same value as A).

Now my question is , what are the good ways to handle this kind of problem?

My another question is, I believe that mysql shouldn't be a single threaded system, but let's say if there are two same queries (they are updating the same table, same column and same record) come in at the same time, how mysql handle this kind of situation? Which one mysql will schedule first and which one later?

Moreover, could anyone explain a bit how mysql work in multithreading support? One connection one thread? So all the statement created under that connection will schedule in a same queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using InnoDB, you can use transactions to provide fine-grained mutual exclusion.

If you're using MyISAM, you can use `LOCK TABLE` to prevent B from accessing the table until A finishes making its changes.

If two clients try to update the same field at the same time, it's unpredictable which one will win the race. The database has internal mutual exclusion to serialize the two queries, but the specific order is essentially random.